# EXCEL Stacked Bar no Date Axis and Date with delay and dilatation

Tags: excel, date, axis, stacked

[Timeline](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xkp1xbbpgggm08y/Timeline.xlsb?dl=0)

In my Timeline EXCEL i have two Charts.

The Combo Chart (Stacked Bar & Line with Markers) shows a Timeeline without format of a "Date Axis". It isn't possible to set the Axis as "Date Axis".

The Points in this Combo Chart are not shown correct! There is a Timeshift of a few Months and a dilitation of more than one year on the End of the Chart too.

[image: incorrect shown Data]

The second Chart below shows a "line with Markers" Chart with a Timeline in format of EXCELs "Date Axis".

The Points in this second Chart are shown correct as  given in the Data-Area.

[image: correct shown Data]

Why there is no possibility to format the Axis of the Combo-Chart as a "Date Axis" ?

Why there is a delay and a dilitation?

How to set up the Combo-Chart to show the Data as given in the Data-Area and like the second Chart below?

Answer (score 0):

Select the chart, open the "Select Data" dialog, select the Lifebalance series. You can see that the X axis values for that series are numbers incrementing from 1. Click the Edit button and select A2:A45 instead.

Now the blue line is charted on a time axis.

Edit after comment: I don't work for Microsoft,so I can't answer questions about WHY Excel behaves the way it does. When I create a horizontal stacked bar chart with dates on the axis, I can see the option for text or date axis when I format the axis. That applies to Excel 2013 and Excel 2016. You did not say what version you are using, but from your screenshots it's at least 2013, so you should see that option, too. In earlier versions of Excel column and bar charts don't support the date axis.

If you don't see the date axis as an option in your Excel file, it may be running in compatibility mode. You could post your file on a file sharing site, and post a link here so it can be inspected.

Comment: thank you, this helps me a lot!!! And what about the last Question: Why EXCEL doesn't show the option for "Date Axis" for this type of chart? It also doesn't show the Option if there is only a Stacked Bar without the other Data (Lifebalance) that i have in my chart.

Comment: I added details to my answer.